# Font Options in Multi Lines of Text fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, font

I am working on Sharepoint 13 and we have a need to change the color or bold certain words within a multi lines text field. Is it a possibility to add something like a font bar or feature to be able to do this? It does not have to be as elaborate as font bar, could be jus the option to change color or bold.

Comment: In SP 2013, *Multiple lines of text* column already has *Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)* options where text can be formatted. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Can this show in the overall list view, not item view?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the “Specify the type if text to allow” option to “**Rich text**” or “**Enhanced rich text**” to enable the formatting options via *LIST* > *List Settings* > click on the Multiple lines of text field under *Columns* > *Additional Column Settings*.

[image]

Reference: [Format the text under column headings in lists.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-the-text-under-column-headings-in-lists-6f376710-16db-4469-82e3-ebbe17a52172)